# plotting integer output from Networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have imported counter from collections, networkx (as nx) and matplotlib (as plt). I have taken the degrees of each node in a graph that I have made. but then I would like to plot the number of degrees vs the degree frequency.
My attempt is as follows:

```
deg=list(G.degree().values())# set the degree for each node
for i in deg:# iterate this list
    count=Counter(i)#count the frequency of the nodes
    plt.plot(count, i)#plot frequency vs degree
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

So I'm wondering if my input is correct and also if my logic is correct to begin with as I'm not sure that these frequencies will even link back to the degrees from which they were derived and plot against them correctly.

Comment: Show the full backtrace. It will show you on which line the error is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try `networkx.degree_histogram` which calculates the data you want.  What it does for a graph G is

```
degseq = list(d for n, d in G.degree())
dmax = max(degseq) + 1
freq = [ 0 for d in range(dmax) ]
for d in degseq:
    freq[d] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks vey much but I can't get the output to show with plt.show()... is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, plot, the freq array, say import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, plt.hist(freq), plt.show().

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating `i` over a `list` of `int`, that's fine, but then this line

```
count=Counter(i)#count the frequency of the nodes
```

doesn't make sense, you're counting `i`, which is an integer. What you might want to do (assuming this is `collections.Counter`), is

```
count = Counter(deg)
```

This will count all occurences in `deg`.